# Attribute binding not working on metadata

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

For some reason I cannot get bindings working for attributes of elements in the head element. Surprisingly, the same bindings do work for elements in the head element.

I've pasted the code I'm using below. The title element get bound properly, but the same binding does not work for the meta property="og:title" element. I've tried both content="{{ var }}" and ng-attr-content="{{ var }}". Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I can fix this?

I'm seeing the following in chrome developers console:

[image: chrome developers console]

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">
  <head>
    <title ng-bind="documentTitle"></title>

    <meta property="og:title" ng-attr-content="{{ documentTitle }}" />
    <meta name="description" ng-if="documentDescription" ng-attr-content="{{ documentDescription }}" />
    <meta name="fragment" content="!">
    <meta name="prerender-status-code" ng-attr-content="{{statusCode}}">

    <base href="/" />

    {% include 'stylesheets.html' %}
  </head>

  <body>
    {% include 'javascripts.html' %}
  </body>
</html>
```

test.js:

```
function run($http, $locale, $rootScope, $route, Head) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    Head.setTitle($route.current.meta.title);
    Head.setDescription($route.current.meta.description);
    Head.setStatusCode('200');
  });
}
```

head service:

```
(function ($, _) {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('test.utils.services')
    .factory('Head', Head);

  Head.$inject = ['$rootScope'];

  function Head($rootScope) {
    var Head = {
      setStatusCode: setStatusCode,
      setTitle: setTitle,
      setDescription: setDescription
    };

    return Head;

    function setStatusCode(statusCode) {
      $rootScope.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    function setTitle(title) {
      $rootScope.documentTitle = title;
    }

    function setDescription(description) {
      $rootScope.documentDescription = description;
    }
  }
})($, _);
```

Answer (score 0):

put all the head variables in an object like this

instead of `$rootScope.statusCode = statusCode;`

put `$rootScope.head.statusCode = statusCode;`

and then use it like this in the html

`<meta property="og:title" ng-attr-content="{{ documentTitle }}" />`

to `<meta property="og:title" ng-attr-content="{{ head.documentTitle }}" />`

strings are not binded between components, only objects

Comment: Also doesn't work. I added  $rootScope.head = {}; add the top of run() in test.js and prefixed all references with head. Same result shows in developers console. Tried with and without ng-attr. Binding the title element to head.title did work.

Comment: you should use content="{{ head.documentTitle }}" or ng-attr-content="head.documentTitle"

Comment: Ah I was trying to ng-attr alternative wrong then, but it still isn't working as far as I can see. Even page rendered by prerender.io shows <meta name="description" ng-if="head.description" ng-attr-content="head.description" class="ng-scope"> or without ng-attr <meta name="prerender-status-code" content="">. Really appreciate your help so far, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working. The problem was that Django messed up the template somehow. After adding {% verbatim %} and {% endverbatim %} around the sections that Django should not parse, the problem was solved.